# Any python api for getting account name by inputting public key?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code, keosd

Is there any python api for getting account name by inputting public key? I have got this code from developers portal, but I don't know how to use it.

```
import requests

url = "http://host/:port/v1/history/get_key_accounts"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

import requests

import json

response = requests.request("POST","https://api.jungle.alohaeos.com:443/v1/history/get_key_accounts",data = json.dumps({'public_key':'Enter the public key'}))

keys = response.text
print(keys)